# Upvoted comments point value

Tags: discussion

Do upvoted comments accrue points in the beta? I have a few upvoted comments very recently that don't seem to have moved my point total at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no one gets points for votes on *comments*, not during the beta or any other time. There is [a badge](https://magento.stackexchange.com/badges/56/pundit)...

If you want to earn points, post an actual *answer*.

See also: https://magento.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment

Comment: I did not know this, somehow. Thanks for the answer!